# script copy sender(s) email address only to the clipboard

Tags: mail.app, applescript, script

I am a blind voiceover user of mac.

The new `Mail.app` makes it difficult to copy the sender's email. I would like to have a script which copies the sender email only, of one or more selected messages.

Is it possibile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AppleScript makes it easily possible !

Here is an AppleScript which can do that :

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSenderList to {}
    set theMessages to the selected messages of message viewer 0
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        set end of theSenderList to sender of aMessage
    end repeat
    set the clipboard to (theSenderList as rich text)
    beep
end tell
```

It will cop the mail senders to the clipboard as following: `John Doe <John.Doe@gmail.com>`

---

The same script without the names :

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSenderList to {}
    set theMessages to the selected messages of message viewer 0
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        set end of theSenderList to (extract address from sender of aMessage)
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set the clipboard to (theSenderList as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    beep
end tell
```

It outputs only the addresses with a `space` delimiter : `john.doe@gmail.com jane.doe@gmail.com`

---

For the beep, just add `beep` before the `end tell` (as I already did above).

Answer (score 0):

Two possible modifications to the very useful code by Matthieu:
    1. You could have it speak each address as it finds it (if that is useful) by using the `say` command.
    2. Some consider it good form to preserve what `AppleScript's text item delimiters` were before changing them, then restore them back to original settings, instead of assuming that was a null character (`""`), especially if this might run while other scripts are running, since it is a global property.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSenderList to {}
    set theMessages to the selected messages of message viewer 0
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        set oneAddress to extract address from sender of aMessage
        set end of theSenderList to oneAddress
        say "found: " & oneAddress
    end repeat
    set {prevDelims, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, " "}
    set the clipboard to (theSenderList as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevDelims
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

An update to [Matthieu's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118767/67990), to remove duplicates and add a new line between each address:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSenderList to {}
    set theMessages to the selected messages of message viewer 0
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        set theSender to sender of aMessage
        if theSender is not in theSenderList then
            set end of theSenderList to theSender
            set end of theSenderList to "
"
        end if
    end repeat

    set the clipboard to (theSenderList as rich text)
    beep
end tell
```