# In mail.app, get list of recipients for just one of the many email accounts.

Tags: mail.app, email, group

I use mail.app to interact with about a dozen different email accounts, which I use for different purposes.  I need to create a list of the senders (or recipients) of just on of those email accounts.  Contacts.app is completely useless as it is mostly full of obsolete contact from previous jobs and I've never figured out how to clean it out.  But since recipient auto-complete functions properly, mail.app must have access to senders/recipients directly and I just want to access that information for a specific single email account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a 2 step process to do that.

Part I

First create a Smart Folder in Mail.

There you will sort all emails specific to a selected account.

[image: smart folder]

You can skip the above part and sort by account then select the messages from a single account.

Part II

Now use (Copy) one of those Apple Scripts (Thank you [Matthieu Riegler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118767/46541)) in to your AppleScript Editor.app

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSenderList to {}
    set theMessages to the selected messages of message viewer 0
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        set end of theSenderList to (extract address from sender of aMessage)
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set the clipboard to (theSenderList as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    beep
end tell
```

Now back to the Mail Smart folder, and select as many emails as you want there (or all).

Back to Apple script, click run and it will extract the addresses of the selected emails to your clipboard. Once done....

Open new Notes or other empty text document and click Paste to get the addressees collected.

Comment: Terrific.  I had been expecting something narrowing down Mail.app's Window/Previous Recipient   function.

I haven't used AppleScript before but your instructions were clear.  I've been mucking a bit to try to change it to extracting the Previous Recipients instead of Senders, but haven't gotten it right yet.  I bet it's simple but I'm not familiar with the reserved terms.  Suggestions?

Comment: Lets mark this one as done and come up with new question since it is a new task. Collecting all emails in a email chain? aka previous (or Original Sender)

Comment: If that's the preferred etiquette, I'm willing.  But the title and question are exactly as it stands deleting the "senders (or".  Isn't it more useful to have them together?

Comment: The method for extracting email addressees from existing mail body ect is different then what you asked for. I do not want to be picky, butt the system here is one question one answer. basically you would be using Automator service to extract all imbedded emails in a message.